# nested array into simple nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
[0] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "2"
    ["name"] => string(10) "Contractor"
    ["statuses"] => array(4) {
      [1] => array(3) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "1"
        ["name"] => string(3) "NEW"
        ["count"] => string(2) "32"
      }
      [3] => array(3) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "3"
        ["name"] => string(8) "RETURNED"
        ["count"] => string(2) "20"
      }
      [5] => array(3) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "5"
        ["name"] => string(6) "FAILED"
        ["count"] => string(2) "46"
      }
      [58] => array(3) {
        ["id"] => string(2) "58"
        ["name"] => string(6) "REVISE"
        ["count"] => string(3) "197"
      }
    }
  }
```

now when I convert into JSON it look like this

```
"items":[{"id":"2","name":"Contractor","statuses":{"1":{"id":"1","name":"NEW","count":"32"},"3":{"id":"3","name":"RETURNED","count":"20"},"5":{"id":"5","name":"FAILED","count":"46"},"58":{"id":"58","name":"REVISE","count":"197"}}}...
```

how to I remove the preceding 1, 3, 6 and 58 from array or JSON

I have tried `array_values()` but it is not converting the nested part of the array

Comment: so you basically need to `unset` statuses?

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) answers your question pretty well.

Comment: no i just want to remove that [1],[3],...[58] from nested array

Comment: try `$array['statuses'] = array_values($array['statuses'])`

Answer (score 2):

> how to i remove the preceding 1, 3, 6 and 58 from array or json

If you want `json_encode()` to return JSON array all the array keys must:

- be numeric
- be in sequence
- the sequence must start from `0`

For example:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
echo json_encode($a);
```

outputs desired

```
[1,2,3]
```

same with explicitly set indexes:

```
$a = [0=>1,2,3];
```

but

```
$a = [1=>1,2,3];
```

would output object:

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3}
```

because sequence does not start from `0`. Same for your case:

```
$a = [1,2,58=>3];
```

which produces

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"58":3}
```

because continuity of the key sequence is broken by index `58`.

So depending on how you build your source array simply remove own keys with i.e. `array_values()`:

```
$a = [1,2,58=>3];
echo json_encode(array_values($a)]);
```

would produce

```
[1,2,3]
```

so use `array_values()` on your `$data['statuses']` and you are done.